# How do I insert a variable into a raw_input query?

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, raw-input

I have started learning Python 2.7.x with the "Learn Python the Hard Way" book. I am currently learning about the `raw_input` function and I'm experimenting with different ways to use it. I wrote the following code:

```
name = raw_input("What is your name? ")
print "Hi %s," % name,
home = raw_input("where do you live? ")

print "I hear that %s is a great place to raise a family, %s." % (home, name)

age = raw_input("How old are you, %s? ") % name
```

I receive this error with the last line:

`TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

How can I use the `raw_input` function in a similar way and insert a variable so customize the question embedded in the `raw_input` query (apologies if I am making a mess of the terminology)?

Ideally, I'd like to output a question along these lines:

`How old are you, Bob?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
age = raw_input("How old are you, %s? " % name)
```

Explanation:

```
raw_input([prompt])

If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.
```

So, when you do

```
age = raw_input("How old are you, %s? ") % name
```

let's say you entered `Paul`

so the above statement becomes,

```
age = "Paul" % name
```

and since string "Paul" is not a placeholder it throws the corresponding error.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. The query becomes: "How old are you, %s?" and when I respond I see the same error.

Comment: did you try `age = raw_input("How old are you, %s? " % name)` ?

Comment: @PaulJacobson if this answer worked for you then you can mark it as accepted so if anyone in the future finds their way here they know it works